# Rambam and Shebulei HaLeket regarding Moshiach

Tags: sources-mekorot, rambam, messiah

[Rabbi Zecharia Wallerstein](https://www.torahanytime.com/#/lectures?v=38333) stated the following:

The *Rambam* says that any Jewish person who wants Moshiach because someone died and they want them to come back to life etc. other than wanting G-d to be revealed is called an apikores...

The [*Shebulei HaLeket*](http://hebrewbooks.org/14636) 
says that all the Jewish people who are not waiting for Moshiach - even though they happen to be alive when Moshiach comes, they will not be able to see Moshiach come. They will die...

1) Where does the *Rambam* say this?

2) Where does the *Shebulei HaLeket* say this?

Comment: is there any way of asking him himself?

Comment: @sam: I went to Ohr Naava's website and emailed them the question. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Perhaps he was misquoting [Hilkhot Melakhim 12:7](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/e512.htm).

Comment: Much improved!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Shebulei HaLeket is [here in chapter 274](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14636&st=%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%95&pgnum=303&hilite=bda30308-8b58-486b-be65-925904d74e03).

Comment: Than you very much! What's the wording?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah I included a link. Do you mean a translation?

Comment: Yes, I would appreciate it.

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah ok first here's the context: he's quoting his brother R. Binyomin's explanation of the statement of Chazal that whoever doesn't  mourn on Tisha Bav will not see Jerusalem in its future happy (restored post-messianic) state. And here's the quote: "whoever doesn't mourn on it is not fit to see it's consolation, even if he will be alive when the geulah comes, and he will be written in the group of the reshaim who do not believe and are not fit for the redemption, as we find by [the redemption from] Egypt that all those who did not believe in the geulah died during the three days

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah of darkness."  It should be noted, however, that "emunah" in this context may not mean "belief".